# When request is made in aws lambda module of nodejs environment, 403 is returned for two specific domains

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, request

When request is made in aws lambda module of nodejs environment, 403 is returned for two specific domains. However, calling that domain alone will not return 403. The same applies to the request module, not the cralwer module.

Executing the same logic locally returns all of the responses back to 200 normally.

This is the source uploaded to the lambda.

```
const Crawler = require('crawler');
const urls = [
  'http://www.ddengle.com',
  'http://www.cointalk.co.kr',
  'http://www.chaintalk.io',
  'http://www.coinpan.com',
  'http://www.hozaebox.com',
  'https://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists?id=bitcoins',
  'https://gall.dcinside.com/mgallery/board/lists?id=coin',
];

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const crawler = new Crawler({
      maxConnections: 10,
      jQuery: 'whacko',
      callback(err, res, done) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const hostname = res.request.uri.hostname;

        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log(hostname);
        } else console.log(`[crawler] ${hostname} statusCode ${res.statusCode}`);

        done();
      },
    });

    crawler.on('drain', () => {
      resolve();
    });

    urls.forEach((e) => {
      crawler.queue([{
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36',
        },
        uri: e,
      }]);
    });
  });
};
```

For my purposes it is simply a request call, so all values ​​should be answered with 200. However, running the test on the lambda will return 403 unconditionally for either www.ddengle.com or coinpan.com.

```
START RequestId: f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72 Version: $LATEST
2019-08-23T08:13:36.593Z    f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72    INFO    www.chaintalk.io
2019-08-23T08:13:36.811Z    f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72    INFO    [crawler] www.ddengle.com statusCode 403
2019-08-23T08:13:37.170Z    f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72    INFO    www.hozaebox.com
2019-08-23T08:13:37.454Z    f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72    INFO    gall.dcinside.com
2019-08-23T08:13:37.873Z    f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72    INFO    gall.dcinside.com
2019-08-23T08:13:38.391Z    f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72    INFO    www.cointalk.co.kr
2019-08-23T08:13:39.153Z    f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72    INFO    coinpan.com
END RequestId: f3cc4977-11af-4ab1-9556-9b778efd1f72
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly move your Lambda into a VPC, then Lambda request is made from a specific IP. I am assuming that when Lambda runs outside a VPC (Default behavior), there is no associated IP to it and it might be blocked by the website which you are trying to crawl.

Comment: However, calling that domain alone will not return 403.

Answer (score 0):

Domain `ddengle.com` seems to be protected by cloudflare and only accessible through `https`.

```
curl -I http://www.ddengle.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2019 08:31:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Fri, 23 Aug 2019 09:31:50 GMT
Location: https://www.ddengle.com/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
```

It can be country block, WAF, browser integrity check ...

Full list here: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-403-forbidden/53308

Comment: Try to [slow down](https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler#slow-down), may be blocked if too many requests from the same IP address.

Comment: The strange thing is that just calling the problematic domain alone returns 200 normally.

Comment: Based on your advice, I gave the slow down option but it's the same. Send a request to all those domains in one lambda function. What I meant to say in the first answer comment was that if I called either ddengle or coinpan rather than array, 200 would be returned.

Comment: I've found a solution that works as intended. But it doesn't make sense. The copinpan crawler object is created separately and called to operate normally.

Comment: Yeah was thinking to that too, the crawler object may reuse the connection and end up messing with sessions ?

Comment: My personal opinion is that it's not a problem with the crawler module. If the crawler module was the problem, when using the request module should return 200 in all. However, the request module returned the same 403 code. All these 403 return codes are returned only in lambda functions. This phenomenon has never been reproduced in the local environment.